# Uma aplicação unica do laravel com muitos banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho um aplicativo com o framework Laravel que eu criei muitos subdomínios para acessar. Hoje faço um ambiente separado para cada um, mas os arquivos em cada um deles serão os mesmos.

Minha dúvida é, se é possível fazer um ambiente único para reduzir o espaço em disco no servidor, mas com os bancos de dados separados.

Gostaria de saber se alguém fez algo assim e como você fez.

Answer (score 2):

Basta verificar este link: [Using Multiple Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#using-multiple-database-connections)

Você pode obter a conexão como:

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

ou

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();`
```

Comment: Fiz a tradução na resposta, porque, aqui é o `Stackoverflow em Português`

Comment: Desculpa, confundi o Stackoverflow, mais obrigado ;)